# Moving slideshow not showing correctly when browser size is smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I have a moving slideshow that shows as soon as my webpage loads up.

Everything is fine when the browser window is full size but when i re-size my browser window it takes a while for the images to come in.

I am using Bootstrap media queries to re-size the images in the slideshow when the size is decreased.

I think it may be something to do with the keyframes:

```
@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
 margin-left: -2125px;
}
```

or maybe the bootstrap CSS?

```
@media(max-width: 768px){

header #container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-size: cover;

}

header .photobanner img {
margin-top: 30px;
width: 150px;
height: 90px;
}

}

@media(max-width: 868px){

header #container
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-size: contain;

}

header .photobanner img {
margin-top: 30px;
width: 150px;
height: 90px;
    }


    }
```

js fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/qwg4vg4w/

Comment: why are you using background size contain when your background images are <img>. Also you are using 2 queries to do the same thing? Also can I recommend you get some working image links in the fiddle so we can see how it's breaking for you.

Comment: I'm new to this, i have a background image that is a filmstrip and the images are moving through the middle of the background image.  Also i had to add the second query (868px) to ensure it re-sized properly.. not quite sure why but it works.  @ajmajmajma

Comment: There is no need to have 2 media queries doing the same thing. Just figure out the break point you want and use 1, if you need multiple break points, add more queries on those points. Right now the 768px query is redundant. The background size cover is not needed, unless I am missing somehting here and you have a background image on header #container in some other css. Because right now you have the backgrounds as image files you are bringing in through <img> and are providing a width and height for.

Comment: Also - I'm not sure what really would cause the images to come in slowly when you resize. Is this hosted anywhere so we could see it in action?

Comment: Ok, thanks i am only using one media query now.  Yes i do have a background image in header #container.  It is in the CSS in the JSFiddle.  I dont have a host right now, is there anything else i can do to let you see it in action? @ajmajmajma